# Request: reopen one of the Big Parasol questions

Tags: discussion

A user recently posted [a question about the Big Parasol Pokémon card](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/59730/fully-understanding-big-parasol). This was somewhat unfocused, so I commented to this effect (and voted to close); the question is now closed.

Now while I fully agree the best course of action would have been for the user to edit the existing question, they instead [posted a new well focused question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/59731/can-big-parasol-stop-the-extra-damage-a-moves-does) - but we've now closed that as a duplicate of the unfocused question.

There's clearly a good question here, so we should reopen one of these. I don't particulary mind which but closing them both isn't fair on the user. (I fully accept there was no malice on the part of the close voters).

Comment: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/254466)

Comment: @Rainbolt There is a difference between two different users posting questions that can be closed as duplicates of each other and a user posting the same question again because the first one got closed due to issues with the question.

Answer (score 2):

We shouldn't reopen the second question as that can encourage users to repost the question instead of editing the original question. Instead that user (or someone else) should edit the old question to match the better one and vote to reopen that one as should have originally happened.

Comment: Why do we care if the user reposts or edits? Closed questions that meet certain criteria are automatically deleted. The original question has now been deleted. And how would "someone else" edit the original question to add focus? Arbitrarily choose one of the multiple questions in the post, and delete the remainder? The title doesn't tell you which question was the "primary" question.

Comment: @Rainbolt Because we shouldn't be encouraging people to keep asking the question over and over again until it doesn't get closed. That first question could have and should have been edited into a better question to get it reopened. If the OP can reask the question they can also edit the first one into proper shape.

Comment: I understand that you don't want to encourage people to keep asking questions over and over again until it doesn't get closed. I asked why you feel that way. Maybe you think it's self-evident why posting a new question versus editing is bad, but I don't. I thought maybe you were concerned about polluting the site with dead questions, so I explained that closed questions are automatically cleaned up if they meet certain criteria (and this one certainly met those criteria, because it has been deleted).

Comment: @Rainbolt When I made this answer it was not yet deleted and it was still very easily fixed with an edit and reopened. Now that it is deleted that isn't really an option but it was at the time. Now this user has a downvoted deleted record in their history which can impact their ability to post new questions and that could have been avoided by salvaging the first question instead of just letting it get deleted.